# Android: programmatically check directory path for external or internal type

Tags: android, path, filesystems

I have String with directory path.
I want programmatically check: the path is in interal or external device memory?

Comment: Thanks for -1. The information's below are evident for you? Especially isExternalStorageEmulated() from @ankitagrawal post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Phone with 3.0+ :-
compare string with

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

if it matches and also check Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated() if both true then it is internal storage else external storage

on gingerbread 2.3 and below:-

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

return external storage path as there was no emulation so if comparison succeed it is external storage else internal

Answer (score 1):

You can find out which is the external path and the internal path.
For external path you can use this:

```
String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
```

And for intenal path, this:

```
String extStore = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
```

After that you can compare you path to check where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Complete information are both posts of @ankitagrawal and @Corina Gheorghe.

As i see getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")  gives different result from getExternalStorageDirectory().

In my device

for path in root directory:

```
1) /storage/sdcard1
```

for path in Android/data/APPNAME/files:

```
2) /storage/emulated/legacy
```

It's necessary check both external path's.
And first one method is not depend from isExternalStorageEmulated() in 3.0+ like second method.